# How to use local storage in React js

Tags: reactjs

This is my code:

```
function EditCourseTable() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [CourseID, setCourseID] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios
      .get("http://localhost:3003/coursestable")
      .then(result => setData(result.data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <h2>
        <table className="table" >
          <thead className="thead-dark">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Course Number</th>
              <th scope="col">Course Name</th>
              <th scope="col">View Details</th>
              <th scope="col">Edit Course</th>
              <th scope="col">Delete Course</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {data.map((item, id) => {

              return <tr key={id}>
                {localStorage.setItem('CourseID', item.CourseID)}
                <td>{item.CourseID}</td>
                <td>{item.Name}</td>
                <td><a href={`/viewcourse2`} className="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>

                <td><a href={`/editcourse2`} className="btn btn-primary" >
                  Edit</a></td>

                <td><button className="btn btn-primary">Delete</button></td>
              </tr>
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </h2>

    </div>
  )
}

export default EditCourseTable;
```

I use the localStorage to store the CourseId that the user click on (when click in Edit or View), but it is store the last courseID in the table, not the courseID that I click on. Whats the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert the value in the localStorage by triggering a function called on click of an element

```
function storeCourse(id) {
  localStorage.setItem('CourseID', id)
}

<td>
  <span 
    className="btn btn-primary" 
    onClick={() => storeCourse(item.CourseID)}>
    View
  </span>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is store the course I select ^_^

Comment: It is Success, thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You need to create something to catch that click, so you can create some function like

```
const handleClickItem = (courseID) => {
     localStorage.setItem('CourseID', courseID)
}
```

So whenever the user click, it will use `onClick`, so you can pass something like `onClick = { () => handleClickItem(item.CourseID)}` then pass the item.CourseID into that `handleClickItem`

Now the handleClickItem has the `courseID`

That's when you `localStorage.setItem('CourseID', item.CourseID)`

```
function EditCourseTable() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [CourseID, setCourseID] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios
      .get("http://localhost:3003/coursestable")
      .then(result => setData(result.data));
  }, []);

//- Add handleClickItem

  const handleClickItem = (courseID) => {
         localStorage.setItem('CourseID', courseID)
    } 

  return
```

Inside the return, the `map` one, just add `onClick` where ever you want the user to click

for example:

```
<tr key={id} onClick = {() => handleClickItem(item.CourseID)}>
```

Comment: in the ```handleClickItem``` function, ```item``` doesn't exist no ? So ```item.CourseID``` can't be accessed in this scope

Comment: Oh my bad, lets me edit it back real quick

Answer (score 0):

Your localStorage code runs when rendered so the last rendered item's id is saved to localStorage. You should use the function onClick.

```
<tbody>
    {data.map((item, id) => {

        return <tr key={id} onClick={() => localStorage.setItem('CourseID', item.CourseID)}>
            <td>{item.CourseID}</td>
            <td>{item.Name}</td>
            <td><a href={`/viewcourse2`} className="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>

            <td><a href={`/editcourse2`} className="btn btn-primary" >
                Edit</a></td>

            <td><button className="btn btn-primary">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    })}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you save data to local storage on items render. All items saves to local storage on key CourseID in render order.
Because of this after items render local storage CourseID value equal last item in rendered collection.

Right chose for solving this problem is saving data to local storage on link click.

But i think you does not need saving this data to local storage. React allow storing this in state.

Example for your code:

```
const [clickedCourseId, setClickedCourseId] = useState(null);
...
render (
  ...
  {data.map((item, id) => {

    return (
      <tr key={id}>
        <td>{item.CourseID}</td>
        <td>{item.Name}</td>
        <td><a href={`/viewcourse2`} onClick={() => { setClickedCourseId(item.CourseID) }} className="btn btn-primary">View</a></td>

        <td><a href={`/editcourse2`} onClick={() => { setClickedCourseId(item.CourseID) }} className="btn btn-primary" >
          Edit</a></td>
        <td><button className="btn btn-primary">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    )
  })}
```

In this example, when you click on View or Edit links, clickedCourseId being filled clicked item CourseId and you does not need to store it in localStorage.
However, if you want to store it in localStorage, you can change setClickedCourseId to your localStorage setItem